# how to change/rewite Laravel php Referral link keep asking for login before registration

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, referrals

how to change or rewrite La ravel PHP Referral link keep asking for login before registration. Please I am new here, i keep posting my code but this platform keep marking it red. i wish there is a way to show you guy my code

Comment: when you click on {} icon in top bar it will allow you add any code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{{ url('/registration?referral-link='.Auth::user()->name.'-'.Auth::user()->id) }}
```

Comment: I already have this in //check for users without ref link and update them with: ref_link' => $settings->site_address.'/ref/'.$usf->id, please where do I add this your code?

Comment: Sir, do I use it to replace this: {{Auth::user()->ref_link}} in my referuser.blade.php

Comment: thanks a lot, it worked.